# Pandas - list of unique strings in a column

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe column which contains these values:
A
A
A
F
R
R
B
B
A
...
I would like to make a list summarizing the different strings, as [A,B,F,...].
I've used groupby with nunique(), but I don't need counting.
How can I make the list ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`unique()` is enough

```py
df['col'].unique().tolist()
```

[`pandas.Series.nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) is to return the number of unique items.